# How can I calculate a point perpendicular to a point on another line, at a given distance, in C#?

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry, vector-graphics

I have a midpoint *p1* that is used to create a line along an angle *A*:

```
double startX = p1.X - lineHalfLength * Math.Cos(-A * Math.PI/180);
double endX = p1.X + lineHalfLength * Math.Cos(-A * Math.PI/180);

double startY = p1.Y - lineHalfLength * Math.Sin(-A * Math.PI/180);
double endY = p1.Y + lineHalfLength* Math.Sin(-A * Math.PI/180);
```

So far so good.

Now I need to create a new line that is parallel to the first, at a distance *D* perpendicularly.

Once I figure out midpoint *p2* for the new line, I can create the line (same logic as above), but getting that point is evading me, high school trig was just too long ago. Here's my current attempt:

```
p2.X = p1.X + D * Math.Cos((A + 90) * Math.PI/180);
p2.Y = p1.Y + D * Math.Sin((A + 90) * Math.PI/180);
```

This pretty much works for 45 degrees, but nothing else.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe http://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: A picture would go a long way :)

Comment: Are you having trouble creating a perpendicular line? Or are you having trouble making the perpendicular line the right length?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `D * Math.Cos` for the `X` coordinate?

Comment: You really ought to start working in radians

Comment: Dave, the inputs I'm working with are in angles. Conversions are required. I'm showing them inline here for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the right idea to add 90 degrees to the angle you're using, but the angle you are using is measured clockwise from the left hand side of the horizontal whereas the convention is anticlockwise from the right hand side of the horizontal.

With the usual convention for angles, I would have expected to see code more like this to find the line ends

```
double startX = p1.X - lineHalfLength * Math.Cos(A * Math.PI/180);
double endX = p1.X + lineHalfLength * Math.Cos(A * Math.PI/180);

double startY = p1.Y - lineHalfLength * Math.Sin(A * Math.PI/180);
double endY = p1.Y + lineHalfLength* Math.Sin(A * Math.PI/180);
```

in which case adding `90` to `A` ought to work just fine.

(note `cos(-x)=cos(x)` and `sin(-x)=-sin(x)`)

Maintaining your convention for angle, wrap your code into a line function, and *you can then add 90 degrees to the angle you pass into your own function*.

```
void LineFromMidpoint(double A, Point p1, double dist, out Point p2, out Point p3)
{
    double startX = p1.X - dist * Math.Cos(-A * Math.PI/180);
    double endX = p1.X + dist * Math.Cos(-A * Math.PI/180);

    double startY = p1.Y - dist * Math.Sin(-A * Math.PI/180);
    double endY = p1.Y + dist* Math.Sin(-A * Math.PI/180);

    p2 = new Point {X=startX, Y=startY};
    p3 = new Point {X=endX, Y=endY};
}
```

Call it once to get the original line ends, `p2`, another time to get the perpendicular line ends `p3`, and two more times to get the parallel lines, `p4, p5`.

```
void Main()
{
    Point p1 = new Point {X=10, Y=5};
    Point p2start, p2end;
    double A=15;
    double lineHalfLength = 10;
    LineFromMidpoint(A, p1, lineHalfLength, out p2start, out p2end);
    Console.WriteLine("p1={0}, p2={1}, p3={2}", p1, p2start, p2end);

    double B=A+90;
    double perpDist=2;
    Point p3firstMidpoint, p3secondMidpoint;
    LineFromMidpoint(B, p1, perpDist, out p3firstMidpoint, out p3secondMidpoint);
    Console.WriteLine("p3firstMidpoint={0}, p3secondMidpoint={1}",
        p3firstMidpoint, p3secondMidpoint);

    Point p4start, p4end;
    LineFromMidpoint(A, p3firstMidpoint, lineHalfLength, out p4start, out p4end);
    Console.WriteLine("p4start={0}, p4end={1}", p4start, p4end);

    Point p5start, p5end;
    LineFromMidpoint(A, p3secondMidpoint, lineHalfLength, out p5start, out p5end);
    Console.WriteLine("p5start={0}, p5end={1}", p5start, p5end);
}
```

Plotting the points results in

[image]

Oiginal line ends (black), perpendicular line ends (red), parallel lines (blue and green).

Comment: Good use of DRY, and this seems to work out all of the weird +/-, sin/cos, etc. issues.

Answer (score 1):

> This pretty much works for 45 degrees

That's because `SIN(45)` and `COS(45)` are equal, and you're using the wrong one in your `X` calculation:

```
p2.X = p1.X + D * Math.Cos((A + 90) * Math.PI/180);
p2.Y = p1.Y + D * Math.Sin((A + 90) * Math.PI/180);
```

Comment: Timely and possible apropos: http://ericlippert.com/2014/07/17/copy-paste-defects/

Comment: Already tried that. No combination of sin/cos returns the correct result for angles != 45.

Comment: Worked for me for a 30deg angle.  You might add sample inputs and expected outputs to your question.

Comment: I was able to get answers for 0-90, but the distances were wonky.

I think for this issue to make sense, I'll need to translate the code to SVG-generating Javascript.